# Cascade update without rule/constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table1, table2 and table3 with lets say ID as a common column (no referential integrity is defined but its maintained programmatically with Table1 considered to be the Primary) .
I also have another common column EmpSalary in all the three tables. My requirement is to auto update all the three tables with EmpSalary when anyone of the tables is updated. Is there anything in SQL server which allows to add an auto update statement to the other two tables without enforcing cascade rule ?

P.S - I have tried and researched several possible options and am leaning towards triggers now which is not my favorite object to implement. Looking for alternate solutions here to see if I can avoid triggers.

@Lmu92 - client does not want any constraints on the db, so no an option. Triggers is my current solution looking for ideas until end of day

Comment: Please show us, what you have got so far and provide a minimum working example.

Comment: @pyStarter - I am not looking for any implemented solution. I just need alternate ideas/possibilities if anyone can think of any. Taking the code apart from roughly 1 million lines of code is not something i can do in short time.

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a trigger or take care of it in your code (e.g. stored procedure).
Or -my preferred solution- add referential integrity (=foreign key constraints) with cascading updates.
But this would require a "master" table holding the EmpSalary values and being the only one that gets updated...

Answer (score 0):

None of the other options worked, so I ended up going with triggers.